# spark repartition / executor inconsistencies commandline vs jupyter

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I wasn't really sure what to title this question -- happy for a suggested better summary

I'm beating my head trying to figure out why a dead simple spark job works fine from Jupyter, but from the command line is left with insufficient executors to progress.

What I'm trying to do: I have a large amount of data (<1TB) from which I need to extract a small amount of data (~1GB) and save as parquet.

Problem I have: when my dead-simple code is run from the command line, I only get as many executors as I have final partitions, which is ideally one given it is small. The same exact code works just fine in Jupyter, same cluster, where it tasks out >10k tasks across my entire cluster. The commandline version never progresses. Since it doesn't produce any logs beyond reporting lack of progress, i'm not sure where more to dig.

I have tried both python3 mycode.py and spark-submit mycode.py with lots of variations to no avail. My cluster has dynamicAllocation configured.

```
import findspark
findspark.init('/usr/lib/spark/')
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
data = spark.read.parquet(<datapath>).select(<fields>)
subset = [<list of items>]
spark.sparkContext.broadcast(subset)
data.filter(field.isin.(subset)).coalesce(1).write.parquet("output")
```

** edit: original version mistakenly had repartition(1) instead of coalesce.

In this case, run from the command line, my process will get one executor.

In my logs, the only real hint I get is

```
WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 1 contains a task of very large size (330 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.
```

which makes sense given the lack of resources being allocated.

I have tried to manually force the number of executors using spark-submit runtime settings. In that case, it will start with my initial settings and then immediately start bringing them down until there is only one and nothing progresses.

Any ideas?  thanks.

Comment: Could you share how you run the job from command line? Do you use pyspark, or spark-submit?

Comment: @HanAltae-Tran I've tried several variations. python3 myjob.py and spark-submit --master yarn myjob.py.  Although I have dynamicAllocation enabled, I have also tried manually configuring the num-executors.  If I change the job so it does a df.filter().count() instead of the repartition().write(), it leverages all the resources of the cluster. if I use, .coalesce(N) for N small, I'll get exactly that many executors.

Comment: Did you try --driver-memory or --executor-memory?

Comment: yes, i've tried to alter them without effect. the driver memory altered in the conf file, executors on submit. i've compared the environment via the yarn UI for both spark-submit 'fails' and spark-shell 'success' and they are identical.

Comment: i've found i can force it to use the larger cluster by calling a repartition(N_large) before the coalesce(1). fragile and seems silly, besides that not being necessary from spark-shell/jupyter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up phoning a friend on this one...

the code that was running fine in JupyterHub, but not via the commandline was essentially a:

- read parquet,
- filter on some small field,
- coalesce(1)
- write parquet

I had assumed that coalesce(1) and repartition(1) should have the same results -- even though coalesce(N) and repartition(N) do not -- given that they all go to one partition.

According to my friend, Spark sometimes optimizes coalesce(1) to a single task, which was the behavior I saw. By changing it to repartition(1), everything works fine.

I still have no idea why it works fine in JupyterHub --- having done >20 experiments -- and never on the commandline -- also >20 experiements.

But, if you want to take your data lake to a data puddle this way, use repartition(1) or repartition(n), where n is small, instead of coalesce.